# What scripture describes the story of Vishnu's boon to Shatarupa?

Tags: vishnu, padma-purana, ramcharitmanas, boon

In [Balakanda](http://www.transliteral.org/pages/z110216211706/view) of **Rama-Charitmanasa** there's this famous story of Manu and Shatarupa's penance to Vishnu (Rama). Manu asks Vishnu to be born as his son. Shatarupa asks for unending devotion to Vishnu.

> Doha - 148 The compassionate Lord then said, "knowing that I am highly
>   pleased with you and recognizing Me as a great donor, ask whatever
>   boon you will.
>
> Doha - 149 "O crest -jewel of donors , O gracious lord , I tell You my
>   sincere wish : I would have a son like You. I can have nothing to
>   conceal from You ."
>
> Chaupala - On seeing his love and hearing his invaluable words, the
>   compassionate Lord said, "Amen But where shall I go find My equal?
>   Myself, O king , shall be a son to you."
>
> Then seeing Satarupa with her hands still folded , He said , O good
>   lady . ask whatever boon you please. "O gracious Lord the boon which
>   the clever king has just asked has appealed to me much.
>
> Doha - 150 **"Grant me in Your mercy , O Lord, that very bliss, the same
>   destiny, the same devotion the same attachment to Your feet, the same
>   insight and the same mode of living."**
>
> Chaupala - Hearing the soft, pregnant, charming and excellent speech
>   of Satarupa, **the gracious Lord gently replied, "Whatever desire you
>   cherish in your mind I have granted; you should have no doubt about it
>   Mother , by My grace your uncommon wisdom shall never fail.**

**My question is which scripture is this story of Vishnu's boon to Shatarupa?**

I have read of Manu's penance in [UttaraKhanda (pg 39)](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/bitstream/10689/12954/6/Chapter4_3183--3262p.pdf) of **Padma Purana** and Vishnu's subsequent avatar as Rama. But which scripture describes Shatarupa's side of the story?

Comment: Other scriptures (Puranas) also mention this but doesn't mention story of penance.